# Motherboard will no longer boot into Linux

Tags: systemd, boot-loader, ssd, bios, pop-os

*Motherboard: Gigabyte B450m DS3H WIFI (bios: f50)*

*Pop!_OS 20.04*

The problem happened randomly after restarted the PC. I changed no files, just a restart.

When the PC turns on it will load into the Gigabyte screen for a few seconds, then it will stop having video output, then it will return to the Gigabyte screen, then finally it will go into the bios.

It can boot into a live USB. It does recognize the SSD (as i can access it from the live boot).

I have tried restarting the PC. I have tried turning all the bios options to default. I have looked to make sure the cables are all plugged in properly.

From other sources i was told it was a bootloader problem. I then followed [this](https://support.system76.com/articles/bootloader/) guide from System 76. "Linux Boot Manager" does show up in the boot sequence but the problem persists, so i cant be sure that this is the issue.

I can't be entirely sure that it isn't a hardware issue, but it seems to me that it is a Linux one (though i could be wrong)

Comment: Did you do an abnormal or forced shutdown which may have corrupted the file system. Not sure what Boot-Repair shows with SystemD boot systems, nor if it can even repair it as Boot-Repair's normal fix is reinstall of grub which you do not have. But report may show something. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i have done a forced shutdown before but this one wasn't. After running the create a report and pasting the link it was blank. I don't know if this was because it is systemd or if there was some other error.

Comment: I did not expect report to be blank, just perhaps not all the necessary info shown. It is a long list of Linux commands to replicate the set of commands Boot-Repair runs. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred 
https://pastebin.com/jRwgAkvU

Comment: Partition table is not seeing the Linux partition's format. Was it ext4, most typical Linux format? I might try testdisk to see if it can restore the partition, so seen correctly. If you reformat it, then it will probably be erased. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
repairs including testdisk info & links
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition

Comment: i can't be entirely sure, but i think the filesystem is Linux LUKS. Im running a testdisk right now, but im not sure if i have done it right.

Comment: @oldfred it says 3 partitions cannot be recovered https://pastebin.com/keFxfsaG | MS Data is FAT32, the other two are LUKS 2